# Why is it 'less', not 'fewer'?

Tags: discussion

When I try to upvote an answer, this is what the website says:

[image]
Why is it (ironically, because it's on EL&U) *less*, not *fewer*, when your reputation is something that can be counted?

Comment: Though this is ostensibly (and in fact) a meta question, it may well be a regular site question, but probably a dupe. You may want to look there. TL;DR: 'less' works perfectly fine with count or non-count nouns; to restrict to non-count is what give gives the prescriptivism of splitting infinitives and sentence ending prepositions a bad name.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/505/4972: 'fewer' cannot work with mass nouns ('*fewer water') but 'less' can work with both ('less water', 'less apples').

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because *reputation* is not a count noun in this sense.  You have “15 reputation” not “15 reputations”.